# How to add a button to a jsp page that calls method on a controller

Tags: spring-mvc

HI i want to add a button on a jsp page , which basically calls a method on a controller.

I know its possible to add a form and a button which makes  submit:

```
 <form:form name="info" method="POST" modelAttribute="form" > 
      <input type="submit" name="refresh" value="refresh"/>    
</form:form>
```

Is there another way of doing this without, using the form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller method will be invoked when incoming request has matching URI. So, basically you need to send a request with that matching URI. To avoid form tag

1. Create a `<a>` tag with that URI and render that tag as button using CSS, Which simplifies your job.
2. If page no need to refresh then make a AJAX call with same URI on clicking that button.